# Transparent raindrop ripple screensaver (having your screen display as background)

Tags: gratis, linux, windows-10

Some may consider this a frivolous question, but I think it's on-topic and it's important to me.

Over a decade ago, I had a Red Hat Linux (cannot recall the release) with a collection of default screensavers. One of those screensavers **took a picture of whatever your display was at the moment the screensaver kicked-in**, and then added the effect of raindrops falling causing overlapping ripples transparently. (With varying intensities of rain.)

Does anyone knows the name of that original Red Hat screensaver -and a windows equivalent, secure, preferably open source? It would really make my day (I tried googling lots of times but for some reason never found anything).

[The picture in this link gives a rough idea of what I mean](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/494270127836955319/) (the screensaver I'm trying to identify had much better ripple overlap quality, and clear transparency not disturbing any background colors...)

A still frame:

[image]